# How can I split a column into different columns

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have varchar column with 3 types of values. I want to split it into 3 columns base on the types of value. For example my column is,
    FactoryName of values

1. ANANTA
2. ANANTA
3. ATL
4. ESBL
5. ATL
6. ATL

I want 3 columns named Factory1, Factory2, Factory3 when the value of FactoryName is "ANANTA","ATL" & "ESBL" respectively.The result should be like

- Factory1
- ANANTA
- ANANTA
- NULL
- NULL
- NULL
- NULL
- Factory2
- NULL
- NULL
- ATL
- NULL
- ATL
- ATL

  Can I do this using case or something else? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Pivot` to transpose the data

```
CREATE TABLE #comp
  (
     name VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT #comp
VALUES ('ANANTA'),('ANANTA'),('ATL'),
       ('ESBL'),('ATL'),('ATL')

SELECT [ANANTA] AS factory1,
       [ATL]    AS factory2,
       [ESBL]   AS factory3
FROM   #comp
       PIVOT (Max(name)
             FOR name IN ([ANANTA],
                          [ATL],
                          [ESBL])) piv
```

or `conditional Aggregate`

```
select  max(case when name = 'ANANTA' then name end) factory1,
        max(case when name = 'ATL' then name end) factory2,
        max(case when name = 'ESBL' then name end) factory3 
from #comp
```

**Update:** If you don't want show the result as single row then remove `max` aggregate

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'ANANTA' THEN name END factory1,
       CASE WHEN name = 'ATL' THEN name END factory2,
       CASE WHEN name = 'ESBL' THEN name END factory3
FROM   #comp
```

Comment: But it only shows 1 row. I want all the values of 1st column into 3 columns.

Comment: @Mimi Then how you want to format the result? can you edit the question with expected output in table format